# Python Select 2 materials on an object and link mix node to 2 color ramps and a noiseand link that each Material's base color

Tags: python, materials

I have one object in a scene and I want to select 2 materials from that object and swap in a procedural camo made from noise and color ramps. I has able to do the operation on one material, but when I add the second material, i get an error about the key from "Principled Shader" Not being found every where I look this is how the context is being shown. I must be linking the wrong object, but I can not see it with the sparse documentation.

```
import bpy
import math
import random
import mathutils
import os

objects = bpy.data.objects

plane = objects.get("AirPlane")

# Materials

matBody = plane.material_slots["body"].material
matWings = plane.material_slots["wings"].material

# Enable 'Use nodes' for destined Materials
matBody.use_nodes = True
matWings.use_nodes = True

nodes1 = matBody.node_tree.nodes
nodes2 = matWings.node_tree.nodes

mixColorBody = nodes1.new("ShaderNodeMixRGB")
nodes1["Mix"].blend_type = 'MIX'

# Create Mix Node to MatWings
mixColorWings = nodes2.new("ShaderNodeMixRGB")
nodes2["Mix"].blend_type = 'MIX'

# Create Links


links1 = matBody.node_tree.links
links2 = matWings.node_tree.links


inputsMatBody = nodes1["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0]
inputsMatWings = nodes2["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0]
```

---

The second Material needed

```
"Principled BSDF.001"
```

Still wondering how to get the Brightness Contrast node already on the node though.

Comment: Your script works for me for default materials. Perhaps the Principled BSDF node doesn't exist in one of your materials when you run the script?

Comment: Would you know how to select a Brightness\Contrast node that's already there? I cannot seem to get the correct name for it.